# Makefile target too greedy

Tags: makefile, target, rule, greedy

```
deps/%/:
        git clone something into deps/$*/

deps/%/ebin/: deps/%/
        compile things and put them into newly-created deps/$*/ebin/
```

I have two targets that share a common pattern (`%` is the `*` of Makefiles)
but unfortunately the pattern is too greedy and does not allow me to use those targets.

In fact I get this error: (xxx is one of deps/%/ possible values)

```
warning: overriding recipe for target `xxx'
warning: ignoring old recipe for target `xxx'
```

Off course rules order does not matter in a Makefile, so I was wondering if you knew a way around that. I have ran the doc a couple times already and found nothing about greediness, specifying order or an ugly hack…

The issue is the same here:

```
deps: ‹depends on deps/*/ebin/ wildcarded› | deps/
deps/:
         mkdir deps/
```

Comment: Rule order does/can matter in a makefile. Also what version of make are you using?

Comment: @EtanReisner `GNU Make 3.81` on OSX.